# Theme Resources for Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Windows Phone has [Theme Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28VS.92%29.aspx) and WPF has [Windows Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.aspx). Has anyone found anything similar in Metro-style apps in Windows 8?

I believe that being able to use the colors selected by the user is critical for apps to be declared Metro-style. Is it just too early for this to be present in Windows 8 in the dev preview?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106265/is-it-okay-to-close-questions-about-preview-and-beta-products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Developer Preview, there is no way to dynamically retrieve the system theme resources from a Metro app. ["Light and Dark Theme Xaml" MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Light-and-Dark-Theme-Xaml-eca02f2b) contains a copy of the current theme that can be used in your app.

This is being evaluated, and may be changed in future releases to make things easier.

Comment: Looks the app is no longer available.